# Движение спрайта к ближайшему спрайту Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

Решил сделать симуляцию естественного отбора на python. Возник вопрос: как сделать так чтобы моё существо (зелёный квадрат) двигалось к ближайшей еде (красный квадрат). Вот весь код:

```
import pygame
import random as r

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
fps=60
width=1500
height=900


class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=(r.randint(0,width))
        self.rect.y=(r.randint(0,height))


class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=(width/2)
        self.rect.y=(height/2)
        self.speedx=0

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Симуляция естественного отбора")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()
entity=Animal()
foods=pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(entity)

for i in range(50):
    f = Food()
    all_sprites.add(f)
    foods.add(f)

all_sprites.add(foods)
inGame=True

while inGame:
    clock.tick(fps)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            inGame = False

    screen.fill((black))
    all_sprites.update()
    asd=r.randint(0,100)

    for it in range(1):
        if asd>0 and asd<50:
            f = Food()
            all_sprites.add(f)
            foods.add(f)

    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(entity, foods, True)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил в класс Animal несколько методов. Вот что они делают:

1. set_speed задаёт направление передвижения объекта. (x, y) - координаты точки к которой он должен двигаться. speed - скорость.
2. go передвигает объект. Этот метод нужно вызывать при каждом обновлении кадра.
3. get_distance - рассчитать расстояние до точки с координатами (x, y).

   ```
   import pygame, math # добавлено
   import random as r

   black=(0,0,0)
   white=(255,255,255)
   red=(255,0,0)
   green=(0,255,0)
   blue=(0,0,255)
   fps=30
   width=1500
   height=900


   class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self):
           pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
           self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
           self.image.fill(red)
           self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
           self.rect.x=(r.randint(0,width))
           self.rect.y=(r.randint(0,height))


   class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self):
           pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
           self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
           self.image.fill(green)
           self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
           self.rect.x = width // 2
           self.rect.y = height // 2
           self.x = width / 2 # добавлено
           self.y = height / 2 # добавлено
           self.speedx = 0.
           self.speedy = 0. # добавлено

       def go(self): # добавлено
           self.x += self.speedx # добавлено
           self.y += self.speedy # добавлено
           self.rect.x = int(self.x) # добавлено
           self.rect.y = int(self.y) # добавлено

       def set_speed(self, x, y, speed): # добавлено
           xs = x - self.x # добавлено
           ys = y - self.y # добавлено
           k = speed / math.sqrt(xs * xs + ys * ys) # добавлено
           self.speedx = xs * k # добавлено
           self.speedy = ys * k # добавлено

       def get_distance(self, x, y): # добавлено
           xs = x - self.x # добавлено
           ys = y - self.y # добавлено
           return math.sqrt(xs * xs + ys * ys) # добавлено

   pygame.init()

   screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
   pygame.display.set_caption("Симуляция естественного отбора")
   clock=pygame.time.Clock()
   all_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()

   entity=Animal()
   entity.set_speed(1000, 10, 1.) # добавлено

   foods=pygame.sprite.Group()
   all_sprites.add(entity)

   for i in range(50):
       f = Food()
       all_sprites.add(f)
       foods.add(f)

   all_sprites.add(foods)
   inGame=True

   while inGame:
       clock.tick(fps)

       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               inGame = False

       screen.fill((black))
       all_sprites.update()
       asd=r.randint(0,100)

       entity.go() # добавлено

       for it in range(1):
           if asd>0 and asd<50:
               f = Food()
               all_sprites.add(f)
               foods.add(f)

       all_sprites.draw(screen)
       hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(entity, foods, True)
       pygame.display.flip()

   pygame.quit()
   ```

все добавленные строки я пометил комментарием "добавлено".

С помощью get_distance вы можете оценить расстояния до еды и найти самую близкую, а с помощью set_speed - сделать чтобы существо двигалось к ней. Дальше - Вы сами пишите.

Если Вас интересуют симуляции естественного отбора, то я хочу порекоммендовать Вам группу [CyberBiology](https://vk.com/cyberbiology), в ней публикуются программы похожие на вашу. Я и сам похожую [симуляцию](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9ZDeV398BA&list=PLOAbO557-ElocHFFmgSa2SwQOpSmzVUoN) делал.